# Spotbugs build issue

Tags: java, maven, spotbugs

Built failed while creating aws-sdk-v2 jars due to spotbugs plugin.

Steps to reproduce the error:
clone latest version of aws-sdk-java-v2
In terminal, go to directory and run mvn clean install

Error:
`Failed to execute goal com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-maven-plugin:3.1.11:spotbugs (spotbugs) on project aws-sdk-java-pom: Execution spotbugs of goal com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-maven-plugin:3.1.11:spotbugs failed: Unable to load the mojo 'spotbugs' in the plugin 'com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-maven-plugin:3.1.11'. A required class is missing: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7`

I tried to rebuild the project by deleting spotbugs-maven-plugin but I that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I had no `.mavenrc` file yet, but recently had added Java 17 to test something via Home Brew. As a result, I started seeing this issue. I created a `~/.mavenrc` and added the following to it:

```
JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0`
```

This allowed me to get back to using Java 8 with Maven just like my default Java version would be.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and it turned out my installation of Java 15 was the culprit. Once I got maven to use my standard java version (1.8 Corretto) I could build the project again. Use `mvn -version` to check which java it's currently using.

Personally I had to set `JAVA_HOME` in my `.mavenrc` file, setting it in my bash profile didn't help.